# jquery adding too many classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: I am so sorry, I did not give you full info. What I accidentally skipped (I had to ask the question in a hurry):

Every input element has a sibling img tag. Together they work and look just like a select element. My problem is that after validation only input tag gets the class .wrong, which gives it a red border (so the img tag is left out without the border). The reason why I want to target the parent which is a div is that for now only the input element gets the .wrong class, but if the parent div gets the class then the set of input + img would look like a one element.

To be faster than questions - I cannot change the input + img combo to select tag.

I've got a problem with a simple jQuery script.
How it should work: check for inputs with a certain class. If the input gets the class .wrong then if its parent has class .trigger-wrapper give the parent class .wrong also. If the parent doesn't have the .trigger-wrapper class then leave it alone.

The script doesn't care about the 'if input has .wrong class' part and gives the class .wrong to all of the parents no matter if the targeted input has the .wrong class or not. Also, it adds the class to parents that don't have the .trigger-wrapper class.

The script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    var requiredInput = jQuery('input.form-text');
    if( requiredInput.hasClass('wrong') ) {
        requiredInput.parent('.trigger-wrapper').addClass('wrong');
    }
    else {
        requiredInput.parent().removeClass('wrong');
    }
}, 100);
```

});

Comment: @qxest yes it does. http://api.jquery.com/parent

Answer (score -2, accepted):

requiredInput is going to be an array of results. So you'll need to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan shows what I get for trusting someone else's comment without verifying myself :)

Comment: thank you. I assumed that targeting every input element as i did was going to be the same as using .each() method on them, but clearly it wasn't.

Answer (score -2):

try with closest instead of parent.

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                var requiredInput = $('input.form-text');
                var closest = requiredInput.closest('.trigger-wrapper');
                if (requiredInput.hasClass('wrong')) {
                    closest.addClass('wrong');
                } else {
                    closest.removeClass('wrong');
                }
            }, 100);
        })
```

Comment: Doesn't address the core issue, which is that he isn't iterating through the results

Comment: I can only assume that it's you that just downvoted a question of mine from over a year(!) ago. Petty of you.